# c# RestSharp: Adding and delete cookie because Statuscode 403

Tags: c#, cookies, httpclient, restsharp

i am currently try to get information of an external API using RestSharp (Version 107.1.2). Unfortunately, in every request I get response Status Code 403 "Forbidden". I now have contact to the provider and he told me, to delete all cookies first and then add the cookie "SMCHALLENGE=YES".

I tried this in RestSharp, but when using the client.AddCookie extension, I receive ArgumentException. I now found another option, to add the cookie in header, but this doesn't work either.

Do you have an idea, how to delete all cookies and then add the SMCHALLENGE cookie?

```
  var client = new RestClient("https://test.de/api/token");
  string resource = null;
  client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("testUser", "testPW");
  string apiKey = null;
  var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.Get);

  //Following execution throws System.ArgumentException: "The {0} parameter cannot be an empty string. Parameter name: cookie.domain"
  //client.AddCookie("SMCHALLENGE", "YES");
  request.AddHeader("Cookie", "SMCHALLENGE=YES");

  var response = client.ExecuteAsync(request);
  response.Wait();
  RestResponse rr = response.Result;
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm a bit further now, and got it working via Postman now. Apparently, a cookie called "SMSESSION" is retrieved in advance via "Interceptor". This value is then passed in the request as a cookie. Unfortunately I don't know yet how to read and pass this SMSESSION cookie before the request in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies aren't headers. You need to add your cookies to the `RestClient` own cookie container. Cookies that are returned in the response will also be available in the cookie container. There's a function on `RestClient` to do that as a shortcut.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://test.de/api/token");
client.AddCookie("SMCHALLENGE", "YES");
```

You can also work with the cookie container:

```
client.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(...));
```

You'd need to avoid creating a new `RestClient` instance for each request. This way you'd also keep the cookies across requests.

Comment: 1) The first suggestion client.AddCookie throw System.ArgumentException: The {0} parameter cannot be an empty string.
Parameter name: cookie.Domain

The second one was fine! I now also received SMSESSION cookie. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, strange. `AddCookie` is just a wrapper around `CookieContainer.Add()`. The `Add` function of the cookie container indeed checks the `Domain` property and throws. I will add the domain parameter, thanks for reporting this.

Comment: Hey Alexey,do you have a more detailed insight into RestSharp programming? I now have another phenomenon. How is it possible, to set the _ServicePoint.Expect100Continue_ variable with RestSharp? I have only a solution outsidde of RestSharp, with "normal" HttpWebRequest: `webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;` Is something similar possible in RestSharp?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am sorry but I never had to use `Expect100Continue`. RestSharp is not doing anything else than composing an `HttpRequestMessage`, sending it over with `HttpClient` and parsing the response. Everything that is possible to do with `HttpClient` should work with RestSharp. I am not sure if `HttpClient` respects the `Expect100Continue` property but it might.

Comment: I added a function to configure headers to the latest pre-release package. You can do `client =  new RestClient(options, headers => headers.ExpectContinue = false)`